# \crefname with multiple language definitions

Tags: tcolorbox, languages, cleveref, elsarticle

I am making a LaTeX template with 2 languages, and use `\selectlanguage{english}` to set the document language after `\begin{document}`. This works fine for the `cleveref` package, except that I have made a box environment using `tcolorbox` and would like to have a different cref name in each language.

```
\documentclass[5p,a4paper]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[english,norsk,nynorsk]{babel}

% Stuff from the .sty file of the project:
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\RequirePackage[english,norsk]{cleveref}
\RequirePackage{appendix}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{NTNU_blue}{HTML}{2E5AAC}
\definecolor{bg_blue}{HTML}{cde4ff}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{infoboxCounter}
\setcounter{infoboxCounter}{0}
\newcommand{\infoboxbgcolor}{}
\newcommand{\infoboxframecolor}{}
\newcommand{\SetInfoBoxBgColor}[1]{\renewcommand{\infoboxbgcolor}{#1}} % command to change box color
\newcommand{\SetInfoBoxFrameColor}[1]{\renewcommand{\infoboxframecolor}{#1}} % command to change frame color
\SetInfoBoxBgColor{bg_blue} % default background color
\SetInfoBoxFrameColor{NTNU_blue} % default frame color
\newtcolorbox[use counter=infoboxCounter,
                number within= section
                ]
                {infobox}[2][]%
    {boxrule = 1.5pt,
    colback=\infoboxbgcolor,
    colframe = \infoboxframecolor,
    rounded corners,
    arc = 6pt,   % corners roundness
    title=\bfseries\sffamily #2 \hfill \theinfoboxCounter,
    #1
}

\crefname{infoboxCounter}{box}{boxes} % also needs to be defined for other languages.
\Crefname{infoboxCounter}{Box}{Boxes}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{norsk}

\begin{infobox}[label=box:info]{Infobox}
Here is an infobox.
\end{infobox}

\begin{equation}
    E=mc^2 \label{eq:E=mc}
\end{equation}

\Cref{eq:E=mc}.\par
See \cref{box:info} for more information. 

\appendix

\section{test}

\end{document}
```

By changinging `\selectlanguage` to `\selectlanguage{norsk}` you can see that the title of the appendix changes (corectly) as does the equation reference. However, the custom reference stays the same. So, my question is: **How do I get the custom environment reference to change according to the selected language?**

If statements, maybe? If selected language is english, then give this name as reference, etc. ?

Also on a side note: cleveref does not work with the language option `nynorsk`. How can I make it work (I think I have to define fig, tab, and all other environments for this language?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redefine the crefname correspondingly each time `\selectlanguage` is called, for example via (I don't know Norsk so I'm using the word "nbox" instead).

```
\crefname{infoboxCounter}{box}{}
\Crefname{infoboxCounter}{Box}{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \addto\extrasenglish{%
        \crefname{infoboxCounter}{box}{boxes}%
        \Crefname{infoboxCounter}{Box}{Boxes}%
    }%
    \addto\extrasnorsk{%
        \crefname{infoboxCounter}{nbox}{nboxes}%
        \Crefname{infoboxCounter}{Nbox}{Nboxes}%
    }%
}
```

[image]